# GmailApp Won't Unstar Gmail Message

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail, gmail-api, gmail-addons

I'm trying to unstar a message in my Apps Script project, and it's not unstarring. What am I missing?

My code:

```
var label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("Newly Received Test Request");
var threads = label.getThreads();
GmailApp.refreshThreads(threads);
for (var i in threads) {
  GmailApp.refreshThread(threads[i]);
  var messages = threads[i].getMessages();
  GmailApp.refreshMessages(messages);
  for (var j in messages) {
    GmailApp.refreshMessage(messages[j]);
    if (messages[j].isStarred()) {
      messages[j].unstar();
      Logger.log(messages[i].getPlainBody());
      GmailApp.refreshMessage(messages[j]);
    }
  }
  GmailApp.refreshThread(threads[i]);
  //threads[i].removeLabel(label);
}
GmailApp.refreshThreads(threads);
return;
```

I went a little overboard with the refreshing, just in case. Still, when I run this, the starred messages in this label stay starred.

**Edit**: FWIW, the lag time between Apps Script unstarring a message and the Gmail UI reflecting that change seems to be getting faster over the last couple of days.

Comment: What does your execution transcript and log say after running? Also, on line 9, you call `refreshMessage(messages[i])` (the thread) instead of calling the current message with iterator `[j]`.

Comment: Ooo, nice catch. Execution transcript inexplicably says `[18-08-24 13:08:57:927 PDT] GmailMessage.unstar() [0.161 seconds]` runs the first time, then doesn't run the second time... so I don't enter the `if... isStarred()` in the code. BUT, the message is still starred in the Gmail UI.

Comment: Why not remove the refreshes to see if that's the problem? Most of those methods refresh the thread on their own.

Comment: I should have mentioned that I added the refreshes during troubleshooting. I have also tried it without any of them, no luck. Other SO posts mentioned that refreshes were mandatory so I thought I'd give it a try `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`.

Comment: According to the docs, `GmailMessages` is an array, so you should use an indexed loop rather than a for...in loop. Loop `messages` with a declared variable: `for(var j=0; j<messages[i].length; j++)` and access each with it's thread index, `[i]` and it's message index, `[j]`.

Comment: Thanks for the idea! I was under the impression that a `for... each` loop would be functionally identical to a `for... in` loop in this case, since an Array is an object in JS? Anyway, I switched to `var i = 0; i < messages.length; i++` in this case, and no luck :(

Comment: From the linked thread: OP has filed a bug report on the Issue Tracker: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/77320923

Comment: Is this information useful for your situation? At old gmail, the star mark is not removed, even when ``unstar()`` is run while it confirms that ``isStarred()`` is false. But at new gmail which was updated recently, the star mark is removed, when ``unstar()`` is run. If you are required to use the old gmail, I also think that it's a bug. If you can use new gmail, the bug has been fixed.

Comment: Interesting. I'm using the new Gmail, but it looks like this bug is exactly the bug that I'm running into.

Comment: After I run this code (or the `Array.forEach` code in the link above), the starred emails no longer show up in `is:starred` searches on the web or `.isStarred()` code... But, they're still starred in the Gmail UI when I find them in lists of messages. So strange.

Comment: I'm really sorry for the inconvenience. In my environment, I confirmed that when I used new Gmail, ``unstar()`` worked. But when I used the old one, it didn't work. So I have been using new one after new Gmail was released. But in your environment, the bug might not be removed. If it's so, I think that there is a value to report this bug.